# Javascript checking if json is empty and parsing value if not null

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am working on a pure javascript project with no jquery involved and I am stuck at a crucial juncture for a while now. I have a json which can be empty or when has value I have to extract ip.

```
var xyz = {} or
var xyz = {"Network1":[{"ip":"172.17.44.59","OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr":"fa:16:3e:56:eb:fd","version":4,"OS-EXT-IPS:type":"fixed"}]} or
var xyz = {"VMNetwork":[{"ip":"172.17.44.59","OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr":"fa:16:3e:56:eb:fd","version":4,"OS-EXT-IPS:type":"fixed"}]}
```

The json cab be empty or it can be any of the 2nd or 3rd

I am facing two problems here. How to check of it is empty and if not empty how to get the value of ip. (issue here is that VMNetwork, Network1 are system generated and hence not known to the code)

I tried

```
1. JSON.stringify(xyz)!='{}' 
2. Object.keys(xyz).length !== 0
```

Nothing worked. Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: There's something you aren't telling us. Given the sample in your question, Object.keys should have worked. Try logging `Object.keys(xyz)` to see what keys it has. My guess is your xhr is adding keys to it, you very well could just expect it to have more than x keys, if you know that the xhr adds x keys.

Comment: Right, but if it was indeed an empty object, object.keys would work. Can you show a more complete example of how you are getting `xyz`? Is `xyz` an object, or is it still a json string.

Comment: Here is the whole json from which I am trying to extract ip if it is not empty

    {"OS-EXT-STS:vm_state":"active","name":"test123-jdx","id":"80e80a",{"addresses":{"VMNetwork":[{"ip":"172.17.44.59","OS-EXT-IPS-MAC:mac_addr":"fa:16:3e:56:eb:fd","version":4,"OS-EXT-IPS:type":"fixed"}]}},"hostId":"bf2ff7cf9ad8358794f95a9614f92b88f2fbbcf688f4efa924bdfb75","OS-EXT-SRV-ATTR:host":"avatar.raleigh.my.com","metadata":{"patternInstanceId":"RegionVMware--fd"},"status":"ACTIVE"}

Comment: I don't need to see the json, i need to see how you are getting `xyz`. i don't care what it contains coming from your server.

Comment: For example, if you were using an angularJS resource, it would have additional properties even if just an empty json string was returned.

Comment: It is plain javascript.

Comment: Are you parsing the json string before doing anything with it? `JSON.parse(xyz)`? None of your listed methods would work correctly on a plain string (which is what you would have before parsing) **If you would just include a sample of your actual code where you send the ajax request all of these questions would have been answered up front!**

Comment: Look at your question from our point of view. If we take your sample code and put it in a fiddle, it works as expected.  http://jsfiddle.net/novjLzpz/ therefore you haven't provided enough information for us to recreate your problem.

Comment: ok.. this helped. 

    `for (var i in prices) {`
    `if (prices.hasOwnProperty(i)) {`
    `// do stuff`
    `}`
    `}`

But still want to get the ip details

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var ip;

if(xyz.addresses){
    ip = (xyz.addresses.Network1 || xyz.addresses.VMNetwork)[0].ip;
}
```

Basically, if `xyz` has an `addresses` property, try to get one of the networks, and get it's `ip` property.

Comment: Perhaps change to `if(typeof xyz.addresses != 'undefined')` just in case they need a false or 0 value.

Comment: I don't really think that's necessary here.

Comment: I mean, if `xyz.address` is false or 0, it probably doesn't have the data he needs, so treating it like undefined is likely ok.

Comment: The thing is I dont know the network, so cant do like xyz.addresses.network1
Its can be anything random.